BQ Table partition data got deleted fully even though 'spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode' is set to "DYNAMIC"
We have a date (DD/MM/YYYY) partitioned BQ table. We want to update a specific partition data in 'overwrite' mode using PySpark. So to do this, I applied 'spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode' to 'DYNAMIC' as per the spark bq connector documentation. But still it deleted the other partitioned data which should not be happening.
df_with_partition.write.format("bigquery") \
                .option("table", f"{bq_table_full}") \
                .option("partitionField", f"{partition_date}") \
                .option("partitionType", f"{bq_partition_type}") \
                .option("temporaryGcsBucket", f"{temp_gcs_bucket}") \
                .option("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "DYNAMIC") \
                .option("writeMethod", "indirect") \
                .mode("overwrite") \
                .save()

Can anyone please suggest me what I am doing wrong or how to implement this dynamic partitionOverwriteMode. Many thanks.
